# my bios does not support booting from usb

Tags: usb, bios

Hello i got an old computer and i want to put linux on it but the bios does not boot from usb.i do not have a blank cd my cd player is not a burner is there still hope for me. thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Does it have a bootable floppy drive?

Comment: it does i just don't have any floppys

Answer (score 1):

Have a friend burn you one. Or buy a preburned disk. Try this http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Comment: i could buy a disc . My CD player can not read writable discs  it can only read.  read only discs.